# Drag file from device and copy to local hard disk drive using .NET

Tags: .net, drag-and-drop, filestream

I'm using this code to capture dragged files into my form and copy them to a specific folder (I have left the copy process out, but I'm using - `FileSystem.CopyDirectory(copyFileDetails.Dir.FullName, copyFileDetails.Target, UIOption.AllDialogs); and FileSystem.CopyFile(file, newFileName, UIOption.AllDialogs);`

```
this.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(Form1_DragEnter);
this.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(Form1_DragDrop);

private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //string action = e.Data.ToString();
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptorW"))
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream info = e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor") as System.IO.MemoryStream;
        System.IO.MemoryStream content = e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW") as System.IO.MemoryStream;
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;

    }
}

private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    }
    else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptorW"))
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream info = e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor") as System.IO.MemoryStream;
        System.IO.MemoryStream content = e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW") as System.IO.MemoryStream;
        ClipboardMemoryStream = (MemoryStream)e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW", true);
        byteArray = ClipboardMemoryStream.ToArray();

        // TODO: Read data from stream
    }
}
```

Now when I drag a file to the form I'm getting the file names (string[] files) and have no problem to copy it into the hard disk drive.

But when dragging a file from a device (say camera) I'm getting a filestream that I don't know how I can turn into a file with the same name as the original one.
And I also need this to support large files and folders.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to read the filename from the filegroupdescriptor:

```
Dim ioStream As System.IO.Stream = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor"), System.IO.Stream)
Dim contents As Byte() = New [Byte](511) {}
ioStream.Read(contents, 0, 512)
ioStream.Close()
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
Dim i As Integer = 76
While contents(i) <> 0
    sb.Append(CChar(ChrW(contents(i))))
    i += 1
End While

filename = sb.ToString()
```